# What is the best way to show "exactly two" using predetermined predicates in propositional logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I need to make a proposition saying, "exactly two will do it" using only the 4 predicates A, B, C, and D where A = "A will do it," B = "B will do it," and so on. All I've been able to come up with is (A^B) OR (A^C) OR (A^D) OR (B^C) OR (B^D) OR (C^D), but I don't think this exactly translates to "only two will do it." Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Your notation is. . . odd, in this context. If forced to work with this notation, I'd guess what you want is $A\land B\land \neg C\land \neg D$ instead of $A\land B$ in your answer, and so on.

Comment: I agree it's strange to not be able to use more generic variables, but your suggestion fixes the problem I was having, where potentially more than one of the combinations could be true. I think I'll go with that unless I can find something better. Thanks!

Comment: A predicate is a thing that takes one or more variables to become a sentence.  What you have are full sentences because they are either true or not.  More usual would be to define a predicate $W$ so that $W(x)$ says $x$ will do it.  The possible values for your $x$ are $A,B,C,D$ (the subjects of your sentences).  You then reuse $A,B,C,D$ as the full sentences.

Comment: $[(A\lor B\lor C)\land(A\lor B\lor D)\land(A\lor C\lor D)\land(B\lor C\lor D)] \not\to [(A\land B\land C)\lor(A\land B\land D)\lor(A\land C\land D)\lor(B\land C\land D)]$